# Knn using caret: how to specify k?

Tags: r, caret

I'm  using `caret` package to train a knn model with the following `R` code:

```
set.seed(123)
knn_control <- trainControl(method = "none")
knn_model <- train(data_train,
                        data_train_labels,
                        method = "knn",
                        trControl = knn_control)
```

I don't want to use any kind of resampling (thus, the parameter `method = "none"`), but I want to specify the `k` - the number of neighbours.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tuneGrid to have only 1 k value:

```
knn_model <- train(iris[,-5],factor(iris[,5]!="Setosa"),
tuneGrid=data.frame(k=5),method="knn",trControl=knn_control)
```

The above can only work with 1 K value, since when you don't resample, it defeats the purpose of training your dataset. So it's simply fitting the model to the K you defined.

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, thanks for helping. You set k=5 in your code, but still you say only 1k value?

Comment: Hi @NunoNogueira, to train a model, usually you try for example k= 2,3..8 and use cross-validation to find the best K. In this case,  you are basically fitted the model with K=5...